# SQLite - How to add an order by to this query that searches from an image bucket

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

Currently I have a query retrieves images from my bucket in MediaStore and it's in ascending order (the oldest posts appear first). How do I modify my query so that it displays the newest images first?

```
String[] PROJECTION_BUCKET = {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};

    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    //Not sure how to modify query here
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(images, PROJECTION_BUCKET, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " like ? ",
 new String[] {"%Download%"} , null);

    Log.i("ListingImages"," query count=" + cur.getCount());

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String bucket;
        String date;
        String data;
        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN);
        int dataColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        do {

            bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
            date = cur.getString(dateColumn);
            data = cur.getString(dataColumn);

            Log.i("ListingImages", " bucket=" + bucket
                    + "  date_taken=" + date
                    + "  _data=" + data);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the last argument of the [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String)) method which is the `sortOrder`.
So instead of `null` pass the column followed by `DESC` to sort descending:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
    images, 
    PROJECTION_BUCKET, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " like ? ",
    new String[] {"%Download%"}, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
);
```